# Capacitors on MOSFET gates in DC motor driver schematic

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller

I'm currently troubleshooting and repairing a faulty DC servo motor drive (Control Techniques Maestro) from a CNC machine (Bridgeport), and discovered some weirdness on the H bridge sheet, where all the MOSFETs have a 1nF capacitor between source and gate. This isn't something I've ever done when designing similar DC power handling circuits myself, usually I'm aiming for nice quick gate transitions to keep the FETs cool.

With the tiny ~70nS time constant, are they maybe using them to slow the transients and avoid EMI issues on the long wiring loom that attaches the driver to the motor? The FETs are attached to a large aluminium heatsink, and duty cycle is likely to be relatively low running a CNC directional axis, so presumably heat isn't much of a concern.

Any other ideas?

[image: H bridge]
[image: Gate drive]

Comment: I had to do something like this once to compensate the effect of a large Miller capacitance at fast rising bus voltage while the gate driver was disabled. Ugly, but on the safe side.

Comment: Not really any obvious reasons. Maybe the above. I can think of reasons why not to. Significantly more detail (layout, device datasheets, designer intent) is required to offer something more concrete.

Comment: Sometimes you might want to swamp out Cgd to prevent dv/dt turn-on on the lower device in a bridge, but these are on all the FETs and 1 nF seems like a lot.  Seems like a bad idea to me, you could just use a larger gate resistor to slow the switching for EMI purposes.

Comment: Maybe an attempt to prevent shoot-through caused by reverse recovery current from the upper body diode.